# PHP - insert data from dropdown list based on another one

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list based on another dropdown list and trying to insert data to the database but there's a problem and suggestion how to do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    tr.method_options { display: none; }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#id_grade_number').on('change', function() {         

        $('tr.method_options').hide();
        $('#tr_' + $(this).val() ).show();

    });

});

});//]]>
```

```
<label for="id_application_method"  class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Grade:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
         <table>
    <select name="grade_number" id="id_grade_number"  class="form-control"  value="<?php if(Form::value("grade_number") == ""){ echo $req_user_info['grade_number']; } else { echo Form::value("grade_number"); }?>">
    <option value="Grade not selected">Select your grade</option>
    <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
    <option value="2">Grade 2</option>
    <option value="3">Grade 3</option>
    <option value="4">Grade 4</option>
    <option value="5">Grade 5</option>
    </select></td></tr>

    <tr id="tr_4" class="method_options" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" style="display: none;">
    <th><label for="id_4" style=" padding-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 21px;" >Your Department:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></th><td>
    <select name="dept_name" id="id_4"  class="form-control" value="<?php if(Form::value("dept_name") == ""){ echo $req_user_info['dept_name']; } else { echo Form::value("dept_name"); }?>" >
    <option value="Networking" >Networking</option>
    <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
    <option value="Web Developmentoop">Web Development</option>

    </select></td></tr>

    <tr id="tr_5" class="method_options" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" style="display: none;">
    <th><label for="id_5" style="padding-top: 24px; margin-bottom: 5px;">Your Department: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label></th><td>
    <select name="dept_name" id="id_5"  class="form-control"  value="<?php if(Form::value("dept_name") == ""){ echo $req_user_info['dept_name']; } else { echo Form::value("dept_name"); }?>">
    <option value="Networking" >Networking</option>
    <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
    <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>       
                     </div>
```

1- the problem is when I choose " Grade 4 " and select one of the list that appear not working and only " Networking " go to the database I look at the code but I can't find why not working

2- When I choose Grade 4 or 5 and return to select Grade 1 , 2 or 3 I want to reset the " dept_name " column in the database (this is only if we select by mistake and change it when updating "

Comment: How are you Posting this to your Form handler? What is the PHP code that is handling the form data?

Comment: Also, I would not set the Value in SELECT, but only in OPTION. When the Option is selected, that becomes the Value for the SELECT. `$(this).find(":selected").val();`

Comment: I'm just updating that field not inserting it, and about the value I just removed before posting my question here.. also when I remove the Grade 5 select the Grade 4 select worked well and don't know how to make both work @Twisty

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I hit the mark here, but check it out. jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mcp3n4fn/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <table>
        <tbody id="first_option">
            <tr>
                <th>Grade:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="grade_number" id="id_grade_number" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Grade not selected">Select your grade</option>
                        <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Grade 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Grade 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Grade 4</option>
                        <option value="5">Grade 5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="tr_4" class="method_hidden">
            <tr>
                <th>Department:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="dept_name" id="id_4" class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Networking">Networking</option>
                        <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                        <option value="Web Developmentoop">Web Development</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="tr_5" class="method_hidden">
            <tr>
                <th>Department:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="dept_name" id="id_5" class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Networking">Networking</option>
                        <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                        <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
tr th, tr td {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.method_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var selGrade, selDept;
$(function () {
    $('#id_grade_number').on('change', function () {
        selGrade = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var nextVal = $(this).val();
        $('.method_hidden').hide();
        $('#tr_' + nextVal).show();
    });
    $("select[name='dept_name']").on('change', function () {
        selDept = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        alert("Selected " + selGrade + " > " + selDept);
    });
});
```

Comment: it work but still the Grade 4 options not working when updating

Comment: now I know the problem and it's when I select grade 4 and one of the options that appear it's automatically select the options for grade 5 and select the first one that is the Networking ,, but I have no Idea how to fix it

Comment: So one thing I noticed when making my jsfiddle for this, is since "Networking" was already the selected item, the SELECT would never change. Without the onChange event, it does not execute your script. Do you have an updated code example?

Comment: no I didn't update the code ,, how I can add OnChange event ?

Comment: You can see it in the example JQuery I put in my answer: `$("select[name='dept_name']").on('change', function (){ });` You can also use `$("select[name='dept_name']").change();`

Comment: same thing.. I just want to know if I can make the options for grade 4 and 5 to 1 
because nothing is different between them so how or can I change it to one ?
and if selected grade 1 to 3 don't select department i want custom text " no department " like this

Comment: Can you build a new example at jsfiddle or fork the one I posted and modify it to fit more like what you want? I don't understand from your response what you are trying to achieve.